# Unable to display image from google place details photoReference value in EXPO project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, google-places-api, expo

I am trying to display the first image of every place returned by google placeDetail API. I don't seem to be getting any errors, here's my code.

```
export default class BarCards extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state.name = props.name;
    this.state.photo = props.photo;
    this.state.price = props.price;
    this.state.rating = props.rating;
  }
  state = {
    name: null,
    photo: null,
    price: null,
    rating: null,
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={HopListStyles.barCards}>
          <Image style={{height: 100, width: 100}}source={{uri: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&maxheight=400&photoreference=${this.state.photo.photoReference}&key='api_key'`}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

I am able to get other information from the json file so I don't think there's an issue with my imports.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot to post the solution but the issue was because the places api call returns another URL which contains the photo. Also the fact that I restricted my key to my android app didn't help... Heres the code:

```
export default class BarCards extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      name: props.name,
      photo: props.photo,
      price: props.price,
      rating: props.rating,
      imageUrl: null,
    }
  }

  _getPhoto = async() => {
    const url=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&maxheight=400&photoreference=${this.state.photo.photoReference}&key='api-key'`;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
      this.setState({imageUrl: xhr.responseURL});
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  }

render() {
    const { onPress } = this.props;
    return (
       <Image style={cardStyles.barPhoto} source={{uri: this.state.imageUrl}}/>
 );
}
```

I used the function above to store the returned URL and used that as my source.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend that you try to hard-code the Place Photo request. E.g. use the following (but replace `AIza...` with your full API key):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&maxheight=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&key=AIza...
```

If the image loads fine when you call this then the issue is with your non-maps related code and/or with the `photoreference` you are passing into the request. I suggest you log out the value of `this.state.photo.photoReference` to double check that it's not null and that it's a [valid photo reference](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos#photo_references) returned from a Places Details call.

If the above request does *not* work, then the problem is your API key; make sure that you have a [valid API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#overview) that belongs to a project with billing and Places API enabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should've mentioned what I already tried but I appreciate your response!

Comment: No worries, glad to hear you were able to identify and resolve your issue! And thanks for sharing your answer; you can accept your answer to your own question so that the community knows this has been fixed.